# When will the type 1 and type 2 error be the same i.e. $\alpha = \beta$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, normal-distribution, type-i-and-ii-errors

Suppose $x_{1}, x_{2},........,x_{n}$ be a random sample form normal distribution with mean $\theta$ and variance $1$. Under the following hypothesis: $H_{0}:\theta=\theta_{0}$ vs $H_{1}:\theta=\theta_{1}$ where $\theta_{1}>\theta_{0}$. If the critical region is $\bar x> \frac{\theta_{0}+\theta_{1}}{2}$, then the type 1 and type type 2 will be same?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please 'take the tour' and read how to ask a good `self-study` question. // In this case, I hope you will show what you have tried and explain where you need help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Maybe start with $n=9$ to test $H_0=0$ vs. $H_1=1,$ rejecting if $\bar X_9≥0.5.$

- Under $H_0,\bar X_9\sim\mathsf{Norm}(0,σ=1/3).$
  Find, $α=P(\bar X_9≥.5|H_0).$
- Under $H_1,\; \bar X_9\sim\mathsf{Norm}(1,1/3).$
  Find $β=P(\bar X_9<.5|H_1).$ You'll get $α=β=0.0668.$
- Draw a sketch with two densities of $\bar X_9,$ shading in areas that represent $α$ and $\beta.$
- Express both $α$ and $β$ in terms of standard normal CDF $Φ.$
  Use symmetry.

Generalize.

Following from the 3rd bullet above, can you find areas corresponding to $\alpha$ and $\beta?$

[image]